How to convert KV in Apache Bean into PCollectionList
I have a PCollection of KV like this:
PCollection<KV<Integer, MyObject>> input = pipeline.apply(Create.of(
        KV.of(0, new MyObject("A")),
        KV.of(0, new MyObject("B")),
        KV.of(1, new MyObject("C")),
        KV.of(1, new MyObject("D")),
        KV.of(2, new MyObject("E")),
        KV.of(2, new MyObject("F")),
        KV.of(2, new MyObject("G"))
));

How can I convert this PCollection into a PCollectionList that contains three sub-collections inside. Each sub-collection contains the objects with the same key.
PCollectionList:
    PCollection1 contains A and B
    PCollection2 contains C and D
    PCollection3 contains E, F and G

The maximum number of keys is unknown and could be different from time to time.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/partition/ is the Python example. https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.61.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Partition.html has the Java API.
